Analytic extension of continuous logarithm from compact to an open set

Let $K \subseteq \mathbb C -\{0\}$ be a compact set and assume there exists a continuous logarithm $g:K \to \mathbb C$.

Prove $\epsilon := \inf \{|g(z_1)-g(z_2)-2\pi i\ell|:\ell \in \mathbb Z-\{0\},z_1,z_2 \in K\}>0.$
Prove that for all $z_0 \in K$ there exists $r>0$ and an analytic logarithm $\tilde g:B_r(z_0)\to \mathbb C$ such that $\tilde g(z_0)=g(z_0)$ and $|\tilde g(z)-g(z_0)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ for all $z\in B_r(z_0)$. Conclude $\tilde g(z)=g(z)$ for all $z\in B_r(z_0) \cap K$.
Prove there exists an open set $K \subseteq U\subseteq \mathbb C-\{0\}$ and an analytic logarithm $\bar g:U \to \mathbb C$ such that $\bar g |_K = g$.
Hint: use the fact that $g$ is uniformly continuous over $K$.


I've been investing quite a lot of time into this problem. I've managed to prove 1 and (I think) 2, but I'm having some hard time in 3.  I'm writing out the main lines of the proof for the conclusion in 2 as I feel it's important for 3. My attempt for 3 follows afterwards.

For the conclusion in 2: I've managed to show that $\tilde g$ defined as $\tilde g(z) = f(z)-f(z_0)+g(z_0)$, where $f$ is some branch of the logarithm defined in a neighborhood of $z_0$ meets the requirments for the first part.  Now, let $z \in B_r(z_0) \cap K$, then there exists $r_z>0$ and $\tilde g_z : B_{r_z}(z) \to \mathbb C$ such that $\tilde g_z(z)=g(z)$ and $|\tilde g(w)-g(z)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ for all $w\in B_{r_z}(z)$. Since both $\tilde g$ and $\tilde g_z$ are branches of the logarithm, they differ by $2\pi i \ell $ for some $\ell \in \mathbb Z$. Using 1, we obtain that $\ell = 0$, hence $\tilde g$ and $\tilde g_z$ agree on $B_r(z_0) \cap B_{r_z}(z) \cap K$. In particular we have: $$ \tilde g(z)=\tilde g_z(z)=g(z)$$
$\{B_{r_z}(z)\}_{z \in K}$ is an open cover of $K$, and since $K$ is compact, it has a finite subcover: $$K \subseteq U := \bigcup_{j=1}^nB_{r_j}(z_j)$$ Now, I want to define $\bar g$ as $\tilde g_j(z)$ for all $z \in U$, where $\tilde g_j$ is the extension of $g$ in $B_{r_j}(z_j)$, a ball containing $z$. I want to say this is well defined since the extensions must agree in the intersections, but I've only show they agree on the intersection with $K$. Also, how can I ensure this $\bar g$ is analytic? I'm not sure if this is the part I need to use the hint provided.

Thank you! Any help would be appreciated.

Any continuous logarithm on an open set is automatically analytic - also two continuous logarithms that agree at a point, agree on the connected component of that point in their domain intersection (or if you prefer, in a connected open set, two continuous logarithms defined there that agree at a point, agree everywhere)
